# How to turn off desktop notifications from Boston Globe

Tags: notification

I subscribe to the Boston Globe. I get news alerts from them as desktop notifications. I never asked for them. I don't want them. I contacted the Boston Globe and they won't help me.  I logged on to bostonglobe.com and looked for (without success) an appropriate setting.  I get many other notifications, including some from code I wrote myself.  I only want to stop the ones from the Globe. I know how to programmatically throw up a notification, but I have no idea how to turn off or block specific notifications.  I'm running Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS and I login to i3 window manager. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an Ubuntu forum, which does not support "spinoffs" like Pop!_OS. I'm sure there is a forum for those users ..

Comment: Maybe someone could migrate the question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

It could be a **Web push notification**. I visited Boston Globe and it asked for notifications.

If you use **Firefox**, type in the address bar : `about:preferences#privacy`

- Permissions/Notifications/Settings
- Click on the Website, then Remove.
- Save Changes

---

In **Chromium**, type in the address bar :

```
chrome://settings/
```

And I think you have to search for *Notifications* or check in the menus.